# Troubleshooting why ADuM4160's internal regulator gives 5 V instead of 3.3 V

Tags: power-supply, usb

The problem I have with my [ADuM4160](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADuM4160.pdf) circuit is that I'm getting 5 V from V<sub>DD2</sub> pin while getting roughly 3.3 V on pin V<sub>DD1</sub>. Have I blown the chip?

It doesn't make sense for the V<sub>DD2</sub> to be the same voltage as what I am feeding to the VBUS pin, right? Could it be the bypass capacitors I am using? The datasheet says they should be low-[ESR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_resistance), but I'm unsure where to get them from. Most capacitors that I have found are SMD. I'm using cheap eBay-sourced ceramic capacitors.

The author of the circuit told me to check my supply for oscillations, but I'm unsure how. I do have a digital 40 MHz scope.

The only difference in my circuit is that the downlink is powered by my do-it-yourself [LM338](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_LM-series_integrated_circuits#Voltage_regulators) power supply. Since my device has its own supply I don't need the switch-mode regulator.

BTW, the V<sub>DD1</sub> and V<sub>DD2</sub> are the outputs of internal regulators.

I'm testing this on a breadboard:

[image]

Here's an image of what I see on the V<sub>BUS2</sub> pin which is coming from my LM338 [PSU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply#Terminology). I assume that this is normal and nothing to worry about, right? I don't see anything like the following when I turn up the volts per division. I can really see the oscillations when I turn the time base higher.
I see something similar on the V<sub>DD2</sub> pin as well.

[image]

Comment: Check you have no short between Vbus2 (or Vbus1 for that matter) and Vdd2 (with power off, and use multimeter on ohms range)

Comment: I dont have a dead short between vbus2 and vdd2 but I do have 25K worth of resistence. Vbus 1 and vbus2 is completely open circuit.

Comment: Okay, that sounds reasonable. When you scope the lines, use the probe on x10 setting with the bandlimit off. Also, just out of curiosity, try putting a 10k resistor from Vdd2 to ground2.

Comment: Thanks for everyones help I think I really have killed it. I soldered on new chip and it now give 3.39v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet says that the \$V_{DD1}\$ and \$V_{DD2}\$ behaviour is the same: if \$V_{BUSx}\$ is connected to 5V, the signal at \$V_{DDx}\$ should be the 3.3V output of the LDO. If \$V_{BUSx}\$ is 3.3V, directly connect \$V_{BUSx}\$ and \$V_{DDx}\$ together.

Ceramic capacitors are by nature low-ESR, and using a linear regulator to feed the \$V_{BUSx}\$ signals should be fine.

You should scope all the \$V_{BUSx}\$ and \$V_{DDx}\$ signals with a [short-ground probe](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5755/1293), AC-coupled with bandwidth limiting turned on to see if there are any disturbances in the bus voltages (ballpark: anything in excess of 1% of the DC level may be trouble). Check multiple time scales (10s of ms, 10s of ns, etc.).

Some ceramic decoupling capacitors (100nF or so) close to the IC on the \$V_{BUSx}\$ voltage pins wouldn't hurt.

Comment: what is a ground probe never heard of such a probe. I just have regular probes that came with my scope. Where can I buy one if I should have one?

Comment: He just means that the ground wires from the probes you have should be as short as possible.